# Windows 7 does not run chkdsk on reboot even when it is scheduled

Tags: windows-7, boot, chkdsk

I have a corrupt directory which I cannot delete and when I run CHKDSK in read only mode it finds errors (orphaned files).  However since it is on my main (and only) partition I cannot run it with /R to fix the errors.  It says it will schedule for a reboot and on my past machines this is exactly what happens when I restart my machine.

However now it seems when I restart it this does not happen and windows boots up on its merry way.  Using fsutil I can see the volume dirty bit is still set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

default value for "bootexecute" should be

> autocheck autochk *

if it is not, right click on it and select modify to change it.

[image]

If it still will not run, run it manually by booting from a W7 install DVD and run chkdsk from the command prompt, once you are at the WinRE command prompt type: chkdsk /r C:

Use this guide to get to the command prompt by booting from the install or system repair  disc.
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial147.html

If you do not have a W7 install disc (some PCs come with "recovery" discs and these won't work), see this article on [how to make a windows system repair disc](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02058933&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001)

.